# Building Daemon or Service Apps with Office 365 that doesn't require sign in

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi

Got the Sample Project up&running, URL: https://github.com/mattleib/o365api-as-apponly-webapp

Problem is, sample still needs user manually retrieve authorization, which is still not fully automatic process to get token, i.e., a sign in page shows up requiring username/password input with following error message,

*PS, as the error message suggests, is this because I'm not supplying the right admin name? I went through the web config and the [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage) but it doesn't seem there's anything I missed?*

***This doesn't look like a valid user ID
Your user ID should look like an email address, for example someone@contoso.com or someone@contoso.onmicrosoft.com.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An administrator does have to sign in once to provide consent, which gets recorded in their AAD. Once that happens, apps using this flow can get tokens silently, without user logon. However, the sample always asks you to logon when you restart it, as it doesn't implement any storage to record which organizations have consented already.

So in a real app, you would have the admin login one time as part of a "sign up" process, then you would be good for that organization.

Comment: Thanks Jason for helping me again! But Matthias stated in his blog that the token is only good for 60 minutes, and there's no refresh token to somehow persist it, so I guess the service won't be very solid after 60 minutes elapse since service start? Here's a quote from his blog:                               _________Note: When creating the application, the application must be created as a "Web Application and/or Web API" within the AAD application management portal.

Comment: You don't need a refresh token in this flow, you just request a new token. From the blog post: "When using this flow, the application presents its client credentials to the OAuth2 token issuing endpoint, and in return gets an access token that represents the application itself without any user information. This is sometime also called an "App-Only" token. There is no need for the application to get a refresh token. When the access token expires, it simply goes back to the OAuth2 token issuing endpoint to get a new one."

Comment: Thanks! Allow me some time to implement it from my end.

Comment: Hey Jason, plz allow me maybe another 48 hours, got some errands to run on my end.